# how to set listadapter for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two framelayout in my main.xml file. I add framelayouts to the class that extends Fragment. 
 my main class extends FragmentActivity and this is Oncreate method of it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment f=new Freg1();
    Fragment f2=new Freg1();
    ft.add(R.id.frame1, f);
    ft.add(R.id.frame2, f2);
    ft.commit();
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/Byekan.ttf" );
    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setTypeface(tf);
    Log.i(TAG,"1");
    lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv2=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    Log.i(TAG,"2");
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s1));
    Log.i(TAG,"3");
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this , R.layout.custom_list ,stringList);
    Log.i(TAG,"4");
    lv1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG,"5");
    lv2.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG,"6");


}
```

when i run the codes, it crashed after LOG no4. that mean `setAdapter()` method do not work. how can i resolve this problem?

this is my logcat resource:

```
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.taxitabriz/com.example.taxitabriz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.taxitabriz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        ... 11 more
```

thank for you that help me to resolve problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The part of your question that says "it crashed" indicates that you could provide a stacktrace here.

Comment: thanks, but how can i do that?

Comment: Reproduce the crash while the app is attached to a debugger (adb) and then copy/paste the resulting stacktrace (via logcat) in your question.

Comment: done it. i edit the question and add the logcat resulting in to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListView` `lv1` is null as you can see here:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException
....
com.example.taxitabriz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
```

The line 55 of MainActivity should be this call: `lv1.setAdapter(listAdapter);`

Make sure that your `listView1` is included within the layout and initialized correctly prior to trying to set an Adapter to it.

Comment: Im sute that it is icluded whithin the layout, because when i set frame1.xml to contentview, it works

Comment: Please add your main.xml and frame1.xml to the question as well.

Comment: sorry,stackoverflow do not let me to add other code in questions.

Comment: my main.xml include one text view that named textview1 and to framelayout that named frame1 and frame2/ and my frage1.xml include one text view and one list view that named listview1

Comment: If the included name is NOT `listView1` the assignment will result in a null reference, thus resulting in a NullPointerException on access.